Is there a 'dismiss' event for windows 10 toast notifications?
In my windows c# program i'm using a ToastContentBuilder to build a toast and show it. The event OnActivated is used to detect the interactions of the toast. So far, I have not seen an event listener available for the dismiss button of the toast. the c# sample by msft does not expose a dismiss event handler. Is there one? is it possible to access this using win32 api or win rt if its hidden from the documentation?
Edit: im using ToastNotificationManagerCompat to access these notification events since its not a UWP app. this has only the OnActivated event, no dismissed

The ToastNotification class has a Dismissed event you can subscribe to.
